# Parametrized solution for motion of radially infalling object

Tags: mathematical-physics, mathematical-astronomy

I have this equation:

$$\ddot{r}=-\frac{G M}{r^{2}}$$

I have to show that the solution of $r(t)$ can be parametrized by $\theta$ like this:

$$
r=A(1-\cos \theta), \quad t=B(\theta-\sin \theta), \quad A^{3}=G M B^{2}
$$

I could probably show by direct substitution that this parametrization is correct using [double chain rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/865479/proving-double-derivatives-with-the-chain-rule-i-think). Assuming I don't know what the solution is going to be, how could I go about obtaining this parametrization?

I can multiply both sides by $\dot{R}$:

$$\dot{R} \ddot{R}=-\frac{G M\dot{R}}{R^{2}}$$

which leads me to:

$$\frac{d}{d t}\left[\frac{1}{2} \dot{R}^{2}-\frac{G M}{R}\right]=0$$

which gives me:

$$\frac{d r}{d t}=\frac{2 G M}{r}+C.$$

I don't know how to continue to get to the parametrization.

Comment: Does this helps  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2140677/399263 ?

Comment: Hmm, I don't see how that helps with the above issue but there is a very nice answer which I did not know about, so thank you!

Comment: Oh wait, it might help actually.

Comment: $M$ and $r$ [in the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2141482/590567) have very similar form of what I need. My $\theta$ is their $E$.